# jquery function cant redirect to actionURL in my custom portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have one jquery function which will redirect to my edit page when i click on the edit icon of the column in my custom liferay portlet..

but some how when i click on that icon its just reloading the page but not redirecting to the page i want

here is my view.jsp code

MY PORTLET ACTION URL CODE

```
<portlet:actionURL var="editrestaurantURL" >
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsps/edit_restaurant.jsp"/>
```

My column on click of that jquery will invoke

```
<td class="editable"><%=temprest.getName() %></td>
```

this is my script code

```
<script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {     
                        $(".editable").hover(function(){
                            $(this).append("<i class='splashy-pencil_right'></i>")
                        }, function(){
                            $(this).children("i").remove();
                        });                        
                        $(".editable").click(function(){
                            $.colorbox({
                                initialHeight: '0',
                                initialWidth: '0',
                                href: "#confirm_dialog",
                                inline: true,
                                opacity: '0.3',
                                onComplete: function(){
                                    $('.confirm_yes').click(function(e){
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        window.location.href = "<%=editrestaurantURL.toString() %> ";
                                        $.colorbox.close();
                                    });
                                    $('.confirm_no').click(function(e){
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        $.colorbox.close(); 
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        //* show all elements & remove preloader                        
                        setTimeout('$("html").removeClass("js")',1000);
                    });
                </script>
```

Anyone can guide me that where is the problem?i cant know where is going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the URL:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="editrestaurantURL" >
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsps/edit_restaurant.jsp"/>
</portlet:actionURL>
```

stores the value into an EL variable. Check that you are not missing  part. And if your javascript is working correctly (try to enter any static URL, e.g. www.google.com), do following

```
...
window.location.href = "${editrestaurantURL}";
...
```